# Combining multiple summary statistics in dplyr analysis

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

For a sample dataframe:

```
df1 <- structure(list(practice = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), drug = c("123A456", 
"123A567", "123A123", "123A567", "123A456", "123A123", "123A567", 
"123A567", "998A125", "123A456", "998A125", "123A567", "123A456", 
"998A125", "123A567", "123A567", "123A567", "998A125", "123A123", 
"998A125", "123A123", "123A456", "998A125", "123A567", "998A125", 
"123A456", "123A123", "998A125", "123A567", "123A567", "998A125", 
"123A456", "123A123", "123A567", "123A567", "998A125", "123A456"
), items = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 
5, 6, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4
), quantity = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 7, 9, 5, 3, 4, 
6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 7, 9, 5, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 
3)), .Names = c("practice", "drug", "items", "quantity"), row.names = c(NA, 
-37L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(practice = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), drug = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), items = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), quantity = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("practice", "drug", "items", "quantity"
)), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to do various analysis. I think dplyr will be my solution, but I am struggling how to put the function together.

My dataframe is a list of drugs which I want to summarise some of those drugs (as defined by the first three digits of their drug code).

1. I want to report the sum of those type of drugs (starting with 123)  - drug123.items and drug123.quantity BY practice.
2. I also want to report the totals for all the drugs (all_items and all_quantity) for all of the drugs in my dataframe (I'll eventually express drug123 as a percentage of all the drugs).

I can do bits of the analysis individually i.e. summarise the total items by this for example:

```
practice <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(practice) %>% 
  summarise(all.items = sum(items))
```

... and this to only look at the drugs I am interested in...

```
drug123 <- df1 %>% 
  filter(substr(drug, 1,3)==123)


ALL.drug123 <- aggregate(drug123$quantity, by=list(Category=drug123$practice), FUN=sum)
```

But how do I put everything together?

I want a dataframe with the following columns:

practice (1,2,3 in the dataframe given).

drug123.items #for drug123

drug123.quantity #for drug123

all.items #for all drugs

all.quantity #for all drugs

Any ideas?

Comment: Apologies @akrun...I hadn't updated the name (done now).

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% group_by(practice) %>% mutate(all.items = sum(items)) %>% filter(str_sub(drug, 1, 3) == 123) %>% summarise(all.items = first(all.items), quantSum = sum(quantity))`

Comment: Hi @akrun - I think I do... I would prefer to run the analysis for each type of drug (e.g. 123) separately and have the total quantities and items for all the drugs as extra columns so I can see what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(practice) %>%
  summarize(items_123 = sum(if_else(stringr::str_detect(drug, '^123'), items, 0)),
            quantity_123 = sum(if_else(stringr::str_detect(drug, '^123'), quantity, 0)),
            all_items = sum(items),
            all_quantity = sum(quantity))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  practice items_123 quantity_123 all_items all_quantity
     <int>     <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1        1        54           44        75           58
2        2        44           42        66           65
3        3        24           19        35           28
```

Comment: Thanks @zack - that looks awesome. Can I ask a question? I am getting an error when I apply the code to my real data... the only difference is my drug code names are long - BNFCode, '^0407020A0' - should this work? I am getting the error Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `false` must be type integer, not double.

Comment: hmm in my experience it's probably the `if_else` function, it's strict with types for the true and false clauses. Try `ifelse` instead for now and see if that takes care of it.

Comment: That said - it looks like `item` and `quantity` in my code(and the `dput` output provided) are type `double` - is it possible your `items` or `quantity` columns are type `integer`?

Comment: I use as.numeric so they are fine. You're suggestion worked though so thanks ever so much.